# Replace the delimiter of first line from ',' to ';' in csv file by Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I got a weird csv file whose header's delimiter are **','** while common rows' delimiter is **';'** which cause troubles for me to read and process it as a dictionary by python:

```
players.first_name,players.last_name,players.vis_name,players.player_id
Duje;Cop;Cop;8465
Dusan;Svento;Svento;8658
Markus;Henriksen;Henriksen;7687
```

I wonder if I can replace only the header's delimiter with **';'** or if there is a way to read such csv file to be dictionary without changing the header's delimiter?

*BTW:* I am using Python 2.7.12 with Anaconda 4.0.0 via IDE PyCharm

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a comma is never used in the first line?

Comment: well,the delimiter for the first line is just ',', no ';' exists in the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the first line with a classical csv reader, just to get field names, then continue reading with the dictionary reader, changing the separator to `;` at this point.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    fieldnames = next(cr)

    cr = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=";")

    for d in cr:
        print(d)
```

result:

```
{'players.player_id': '8465', 'players.vis_name': 'Cop', 'players.first_name': 'Duje', 'players.last_name': 'Cop'}
{'players.player_id': '8658', 'players.vis_name': 'Svento', 'players.first_name': 'Dusan', 'players.last_name': 'Svento'}
{'players.player_id': '7687', 'players.vis_name': 'Henriksen', 'players.first_name': 'Markus', 'players.last_name': 'Henriksen'}
```

PS: my previous solution involved reading/writing to a `StringIO`, but the current one is much more elegant.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution, it works for me, Thanks for your detailed explanation~